# Gini index - formal or heuristic?

Tags: data-mining, gini

Gini index is quite often used in constructing decision trees in data mining for attribute selection and attribute split point. Is Gini coefficient just a heuristic or can we formally  explain why it's defined the way it is?

Comment: Are you saying that a heuristic is what we cannot formally explain how we define it?

Comment: No, sorry. The formulation of my question isn't very precise. I'm asking whether we can DERIVE the formula somehow, or PROVE it. Every heuristic method can be defined formally and the question is whether gini index is an example of a heuristic approach.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decision tree learning](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155710/decision-tree-learning)

Comment: You may find heading to the econometric literature regarding income distribution inequality proves enlightening regarding the Gini coefficient's desirable and undesirable qualities **in the context for which it was developed**. An approachable comparative review is Kawachi, I., & Kennedy, B. P. (1997). The relationship of income inequality to mortality: Does the choice of indicator matter? *Social Science & Medicine*, 45(7), 1121–1127.

Comment: A more recent comparative article on income distribution inequality measures addresses some of the drawback, compared with, e.g., the Thiel index, among others: Frank, M. W. (2014). [A New State-Level Panel Of Annual Inequality Measures Over the Period 1916–2015](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/6395181.pdf). *Journal of Business Strategies*, 31(1), 241–263.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a formal proof for you.

But from a quick look, the Gini is the **probability of two randomly chosen items having the same type**, isn't it? That sounds like a way to formally derive it from a simple, probabilistic model.

At least for the variant of Gini that I use mostly, which is this one:

$$G:=\sum_i p_i^2$$

where $p_i$ is the probability of class $i$ occurring. For this index, $1$ indicates a pure result, and $0$ would be maximal impurity. Some people use $1-G$ for consistency with other measures, but that obviously does not make a whole lot of a differences - it's just the opposite probability.

Comment: Gini is the probability of two randomly chosen items having the same type - maybe you could explain how you figured it out? I'd say the opposite - gini index equal 0 means that two randomly chosen items certainly belong to the same class.

Comment: But I'm still not sure what's the connection between gini index and calculating a probability.

Comment: There are different variations of the index. Somewhat like similarity and dissimilarity. There are even some that range from 0 to 10000... Which equation are you using *exactly* (you may want to update your question with this)?

Comment: Yes, I meant 1−G variant, it makes sense now.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if the [following interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning#Gini_impurity) of $1-G$ is correct: 'Gini impurity can be computed by summing the probability of each item being chosen times the probability of a mistake in categorizing that item.' I don't quite understand why it's true, because  I can't see why $p_i$ is the probability of choosing an item. Rather, it's just the probability of choosing an item in class $i$.

Comment: Terms are used differently by different peopel. item is not necessarily the same as an instance. In itemset mining, and item is what you would call a class, I guess.

Comment: Then I'd rather say 'Gini impurity can be computed by summing the probability of choosing an item belonging to class $i$ times the probability of a mistake in categorizing that item.'

Answer (score 0):

Gini index defined for a discrete probability distribution is a measure for inherent 'randomness' in the distribution. For a two class problem, with probabilities $p, 1-p$, it is given by $2p(1-p)$. All the outcomes belong to the same class, if $p$ equals 0 or 1 in which case the randomness in the distribution is 0. This is captured by Gini, which evaluates to zero in these cases. One can also intuitively see that for $p=1/2$ we have maximum 'randomness' and the Gini criteria rightly peaks at this point.

Interpreting it as a probability it represents the probability that two consecutively drawn labels are different. Answer by @anony-mousse explains this further in general case.